# How add new key with update in Arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I have the following document for example :

```
{
    "name" : "sara",
    "family" : "schwimmer",
    "age" : 23,
    "Address": {
      "StateID": 12,
      "Phone": 0,
      "ZipCode": 0
    },
    "create_date": "2021-08-25 17:55:03"
  }
```

i want to add new key in Address to be like below:

```
"Address": {
          "StateID": 12,
          "Phone": 0,
          "ZipCode": 0,
          "StateName" : "NW"
        }
```

so i wrote my update as fllowing:

```
FOR p IN Person
    FOR a IN Area FILTER p.Address.StateID == a.ID
        UPDATE {_key : p._key, p.Address.StateName : a.Name} IN Person
```

I get an error when i run this query, so i tried to turn p.Address.StateName into [p.Address.StateName] or "p.Address.StateName" , it executes successfully after execution but does not add new StateName key to address. How do I write a query to add a new key to Address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR p IN Person
    FOR a IN Area FILTER p.Address.StateID == a.ID
        UPDATE {_key : p._key, Address: MERGE(p.Address, { StateName: Name} ) } IN Person
```

Try this, use `MERGE` to merge the existing `Address` key with the new mini object you created that only has `StateName` in it.

Actually, this may also be possible:

```
FOR p IN Person
    FOR a IN Area FILTER p.Address.StateID == a.ID
        UPDATE {_key : p._key, Address: { StateName: Name} } IN Person
```

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-update.html
This page shows some available options on the `UPDATE` that deal with how to remove keys, merge objects, etc.